# Use regex on catch all route rewrites in next.js

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to implement pagination in my application by rewriting numbers in the path to the query var `?page`. I got it to work more or less, but the [string part of the path gets cut in half](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGHm2.png).

My `next.config.js` looks like this:

```js
const withImages = require('next-images');

module.exports = withImages({
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      { source: '/categoria/:slug*(\\w{1,})', destination: '/category/:slug*' },
      { source: '/categoria/:slug*(\\w{1,})/:page(\\d{1,})', destination: '/category/:slug*/?page=:page' },
    ];
  }
});
```

The route I'm working with is `/category/[...slug]`.

I tried changing `\\w{1,}` to `\\w+`, `[a-z-]{1,}`, `[a-z-]+` and all of them ended up giving the same result.